# ApiClient with http communication in Qt

Tags: c++, c++14, api, qt, client

This is my first code review request on this page. I tried to simplify my ApiClient as much as possible. The full version is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/0xFEEDC0DE64/QtZeiterfassung/blob/master/zeiterfassunglib/zeiterfassungapi.h).

I thought very long about how to design the API client with the Qt framework. The QNetworkAccessManager returns a raw pointer to a QNetworkReply. I don't know what happens when I delete the QNetworkAccessManager before the reply finished. I also don't know if I should delete the reply myself. In the following code I do (using the destructor of `std::unique_ptr`).

One important requirement is that the ApiClient must support multiple requests at a time. That's why the ApiClient itself has no finished signals and instead returns reply-objects (with their own `finished()` signal).

First, this is how I use the ApiClient (sometimes I don't use the QEventLoop and instead use `finished()` slots in diverse widgets)

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QDebug>

#include "mycustomapiclient.h"
#include "mycustomreply.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyCustomApiClient client(&app);

    {
        auto reply = client.getCustom(QDate::currentDate());

        QEventLoop eventLoop(&app);
        QObject::connect(reply.get(), &MyCustomReply::finished,
                         &eventLoop, &QEventLoop::quit);
        eventLoop.exec();

        if(reply->success())
        {
            for(const auto &item : reply->things())
                qDebug() << item.intMember << item.stringMember;
        }
        else
            qCritical() << "request not successful" << reply->errorString();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then here is the MyCustomApiClient. The client is only responsible for creating the correct requests (containing all necessary data). It does not parse any results:

```
#ifndef MYCUSTOMAPICLIENT_H
#define MYCUSTOMAPICLIENT_H

#include <memory>

#include <QObject>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>

#include "mycustomreply.h"

class MyCustomApiClient : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyCustomApiClient(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) :
        QObject(parent),
        m_manager(new QNetworkAccessManager(this))
    {}

    std::unique_ptr<MyCustomReply> getCustom(const QDate &date)
    {
        QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(QStringLiteral("http://example.com/api.php")));

        QByteArray data;

        {
            QJsonObject obj {
                { "type", "custom" },
                { "date", date.toString(QStringLiteral("yyyyMMdd")) }
            };
            data = QJsonDocument(obj).toJson();
        }

        return std::make_unique<MyCustomReply>(
            std::unique_ptr<QNetworkReply>(m_manager->post(request, data)), this
        );
    }

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *m_manager;
};

#endif // MYCUSTOMAPICLIENT_H
```

And finally the reply class (responsible for parsing the returned JSON from webserver):

```
#ifndef MYCUSTOMREPLY_H
#define MYCUSTOMREPLY_H

#include <memory>

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QJsonParseError>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QJsonObject>

class MyCustomReply : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyCustomReply(std::unique_ptr<QNetworkReply> &&reply,
                  QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) :
        QObject(parent),
        m_reply(std::move(reply)),
        m_success(false)
    {
        Q_ASSERT(m_reply != Q_NULLPTR);
        connect(m_reply.get(), &QNetworkReply::finished,
                this, &MyCustomReply::requestFinished);
    }

    struct SomeThing
    {
        int intMember;
        QString stringMember;
    };

    bool success() const { return m_success; }
    const QString &errorString() const { return m_errorString; }
    const QVector<SomeThing> &things() const { return m_things; }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void finished();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void requestFinished()
    {
        if(m_reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
        {
            m_errorString = m_reply->errorString();
            goto after;
        }

        {
            QJsonParseError error;
            auto document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(m_reply->readAll(), &error);

            if(error.error != QJsonParseError::NoError)
            {
                m_errorString = error.errorString();
                goto after;
            }

            if(!document.isArray())
            {
                m_errorString = tr("JSON document is not an array!");
                goto after;
            }

            auto arr = document.array();

            for(const auto &val : arr)
            {
                if(!val.isObject())
                {
                    m_errorString = tr("Value in json array is not an object!");
                    goto after;
                }

                auto obj = val.toObject();

                m_things.append({
                    obj[QStringLiteral("intMember")].toInt(),
                    obj[QStringLiteral("stringMember")].toString()
                });
            }
        }

        m_success = true;

        after:
        Q_EMIT finished();
    }

private:
    QNetworkReply *m_replyy;
    std::unique_ptr<QNetworkReply> m_reply;
    bool m_success;
    QString m_errorString;
    QVector<SomeThing> m_things;
};

#endif // MYCUSTOMREPLY_H
```

What do you think about this pattern? Is the memory management done correctly for c++14?

Answer (score 1):

The code does a lot of things that it shouldn't do, please don't create a secondary QEventLoop (your QCoreApplication already has one and one on top of that will block the first)

connect the success of the network access to a function or a lambda to execute the code you want instead of finishing the event loop:

```
   QObject::connect(reply.get(), &MyCustomReply::finished,
                     [](QNetworkReply *reply){ 

     });
```

don't use std::unique_ptr in QObjects because you shouldn't explicitly delete them if they are used in signals / slots, you should instead call deleteLater() on them.

Comment: Do you suggest calling deleteLater() from a custom deleter in unique_ptr? I really want to hand ownership of the QNetworkReply to my custom reply. I generally tried to avoid lambdas as I had crashes with slots being called who's `this` has already been deleted!

Comment: as you can see my lambda don't have a this. you should only capture what you need. But I prefer to pass a method pointer too. about the unique_ptr it's not up to me to say as I usually share my replies. if you are certain that it's unique, you can use a custom deleter.